# c# TimeSpan преобразование

Tags: c#, datetime

Уважаемые товарищи знатоки, в каком виде лучше работать со временем в программах? DateTime или TimeSpan? Раньше в php использовал timestamp с преобразованием в дату время, а тут как то сложновато с этим, поэтому возникли сомнения, может не стоит timestamp лишних усилий? Если стоит, то как легче всего конвертировать его в дату-время?

Comment: Где Вы видите тип `timestamp` в C#?

Comment: int timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;   вот такое сделал, но дальше с ним работать че то трудно

Comment: Это `UNIX` формат времени. Очень удобен в каких то моментах. Для фреймворка ниже `4.6` - только вручную: `int unixTime = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;`. Для `.NET 4.6` уже добавили готовый вариант: `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`.

Comment: @Alexis, раз уж начали, оформите в полноценный ответ с преобразованием в обе стороны

Comment: @rdorn, готово, если есть чем дополнить\поправить - отредактируйте ответ, под рукой нету 4.6, он остался на рабочем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Timestamp` в `PHP` - это `UNIX` формат времени, насколько я помню `PHP`. Этот формат очень удобен в каких то моментах.

Для `.NET` ниже, чем `4.6` - только вручную:

```
// Конвертация в UNIX время
var unixTime = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

// Конвертация в TimeSpan
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(unixTime);

// Конвертация в DateTime
var dateTime = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(unixTime);
```

Для `.NET 4.6` уже добавили готовый вариант:

```
// Конвертация в UNIX время
var unixTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

// Конвертация в DateTime
var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(unixTime).DateTime;
```

---

**Документация:**

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Да вроде как все нормально. Разве что пару ссылок на документацию оставить для тех, кому гугл враг

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите `TimeSpan` (если вы имеете ввиду это) хранит только время поэтому с ним очень удобно работать **но только со временем**.

А с `DateTime` удобно работать и со временем и с датой (но если вам надо только дата то надо хитро отсоединять от времени, так как нет больше хранение для даты)
К примеру так:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:hh mm ss}", DateTime.Now);
```

также и можно отделить и время, но это будет уже глупо, так как у нас есть `TimeSpan` который работает только со временем

Comment: `TimeSpan` определяет отрезок времени, без привязки начала отрезка к конкретному моменту, а не время как таковое. Причем прекрасно понимает отрезки заданные, например, количеством дней. Для полноценной работы со временем все равно нужен `DateTime`

Comment: Ну я так вкратце объяснил (я подросток мне можно) ;)